# Ubuntu 22.04 reboots if I run glmark2 and high intensive graphics games

Tags: nvidia, games, intel, gigabyte

I have Ubuntu 22.04LTS running on a pc that got:

```
Gigabyte Z790 Gaming X AX motherboard
Intel 14700 cpu
96Gb Crucial DDR5 Memory
MSI GForce 1070 with 8GB DDR5 
Corsair HX850 psu
```

Every time I use the

```
glmark2 --fullscreen --show-all-options
```

command under 4K this pc reboots at the squid test. However, under 1080p this collection of tests ends. Also, highly intensive graphics games just reboot the pc (4k or 1080p). Is this a driver issue? a PSU issue? How to be sure?

This machine starts and so far works well for anything but highly intensive graphics applications.